# Scientist makes a deal with a demon

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, demons, souls

A scientist who has led a drab but blameless life decides to sell his soul to a demon, or maybe the Devil himself, in exchange for a task. If memory serves, the demon heads the terrestrial branch of Hell, but is only one of many in the Universe. He is not in charge of Hell, but hopes to win the next election, for he is not only clever, but justifiably proud of his work on Earth. He looks forward to providing this puny man with whatever he wants, which will take only a finite amount of time; he can return through time and resume his own ambitions. It doesn't matter whether the man wants wealth, pleasure, or fame; the task will not take long from his point of view, and another soul will be lost to heaven forever. So the demon agrees readily before hearing what the task is. It's always worked before. Heaven trembles.

And then the scientist states his terms. The demon's task is to provide the scientist with safe transportation and measuring instruments in space and time, because he has never felt much attachment to other people but is curious about everything. He will deduce the physical laws, structure, and history of the entire Universe. Oh, and he wants no hints or interruptions, so please be silent; he will deduce all this by himself. The demon exclaims, more or less, "But that will take longer than the entire duration of the cosmos!" He realizes that having been stung like this, he will never be elected to a higher position even if he still wants to after returning from so long a period as the scientist's assistant. Heaven smiles. The scientist directs the demon to the Earth's core, where, he says, he would like to resolve some longstanding questions in physics.

The story was read in an English-language anthology, probably in the 1960s or 70s.

Comment: My first thought is Haldeman's "I of Newton", but the twist there involves the scientist telling the Devil to "get lost".

Comment: Another partial match, "The Devil and Simon Flagg" (https://simonsingh.net/books/fermats-last-theorem/wacky-fermat-stuff/devilish-short-story/)

Comment: Interesting. I don't think I've read "I of Newton", though. Others who are curious can read the plot of the _Twilight Zone_ episode [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_of_Newton).

Comment: I know and love "The Devil and Simon Flagg"! Read it first in _Fantasia Mathematica_ in the 1960s. But that ain't it either.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deals_with_the_Devil_in_popular_culture#In_print

Comment: Thanks, Valorum, I already checked that source but nothing seemed to match. Lorendiac, YES, it probably is "Pact" by Poul Anderson, as that does include an election in Hell and the style of the quotation in the previous post looks right. But the story link is not reachable ("takes too long"). The covers in ISFDB are not readily familiar but I have a glimmer of recognition for [one](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?35722) of them and did read other stories in that anthology. Maybe I read it in a library copy without the original dust jacket. Please post an answer with a bit more information.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnfK7.png

Comment: Bingo. I forgot many details but it's still a very enjoyable story. Thank you all for finding it again.

Comment: I think it's honestly debatable as to whether this question, or the other one, is better, but the other one already had a question duped to it, and it is older, so I erred that direction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [noted by Lorendiac](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/223963/scientist-makes-a-deal-with-a-demon/223967#comment612740_223963), this does match with "[Pact](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58310)", by Poul Anderson (under the pen name of Winston P. Sanders), available [here](https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v017n02_1959-08_PDF/Fantasy__Science_Fiction_v017n02_1959-08_PDF#page/n115/mode/2up). This was the answer to [Short story fantasy elections in Hell](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/177288/short-story-fantasy-elections-in-hell), where they note that Ashmadai is trying to win an election in Hell, and makes a deal with Professor Clipp to have him retrieve the Seal of Solomon in exchange for one request fulfilled on his death bed.

The section with Clipp's request:

> ‘Yes... Carry my soul along.
> You know the ways and methods,
> I presume. I wish to explore the
> material universe.”

> “What?”

> “The entire cosmos.” Clipp
> plucked feverishly at his blankets.
> “I don’t want anything, including
> knowledge, handed me on a platter. I want to find out for myself.
> We can start by studying the interior of the Earth. Some interesting problems to be solved there,
> you know, core structure and magnetism and whatnot. Then the sun.
> I could happily spend a thousand
> years, I think, studying nuclear reactions under solar conditions, not
> to speak of the corona and sunspots. Then the planets. Then
> Alpha Centauri and its planets.
> And so on and on. Of course, cosmological questions will require
> us to shuttle a good deal in time
> also. . . .” His longing blazed so
> brightly that Ashmadai covered
> eyes with one wing-flap. “The
> metagalactic space-time universe!
> I cannot imagine myself ever losing interest in its origin, evolution.
> structure, its— yes— its destiny—”

> “But that’ll take a hundred billion years!” screamed Ashmadai.

> Clipp gave him a toothless
> wolfs grin. “Ah, so? Before that
> time, probably entropy will be
> level, the stars exhausted, space
> will have expanded to its maximum radius, collapsed again and
> started re-expanding. A whole new
> cycle of creation will have begun,”

> “Yes,” Ashmadai sobbed.

> “Wonderful!” beamed Clipp.
> “A literally eternal research project, and no reports to file or
> grants to apply for!”

> “But I have work to do!”

> “Too bad,” said Clipp unfeelingly. “Remember, I shall not
> want any of your idiotic conversation. You are nothing but my
> means of transport. Which puts me
> one up on Kepler. I wonder if perhaps he too, and— ah... ah..."